# How to use web API in vb

Tags: vb.net, api

The API i wish to use is a HTTP GET.

However, I'm not sure how to implement this into my application.
This is for looking up IP addresses, so i want the user to input the IP address, then it will send details from the API back. How would i declare the IP address in the application? say, "website.com/api/ipaddress"

I would imagine something like this

```
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim iplookup As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://website.com/api/ipaddress")
```

But i'm not sure what should come after that. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the API have documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. @zaggler

Comment: What API are you using? Its hard to help when you did not mention the API...

Comment: ipinfo.io @zaggler

Answer (score 2):

The site you mention does have an API: https://ipinfo.io/developers
It just doesn't show examples in vb.net.  From it I would infer that URL you are looking for is 'http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json' where the 8.8.8.8 is replaced with the IP you wish to query about.

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim iplookup As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/json")
```

It should return a JSON formatted string like this.  What do you want to do with it?

```
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

Comment: Perfect, what i was looking for, Json format is good for now! :)